# Migrating from speech-to-text-V1 to speech-to-text-V2

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Is there any guid or chitsheet for migrating my speech-to-text-V1 based application to speech-to-text-V2?
In particular, the request is now including "recognizer_id". What does it represent?

I tried searching GCP and web documentation and references.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about python, the following API reference describes it!

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/speech/latest/google.cloud.speech_v2.types.CreateRecognizerRequest

> str The ID to use for the Recognizer, which will become the final
> component of the Recognizer's resource name. This value should be 4-63
> characters, and valid characters are /a-z][0-9]-/.

For other languages, there should be a description in the API reference for creating a Recognizer.

Comment: Thanks. So I create the recognizer_id. I assume that if I have several recognizers, each must have a unique recognizer_id.